# Docker Compose - invalid variable

Tags: docker-compose

I have docker compose yml file in my project file.

When try to run the below commend i get the below error.

> docker-compose up

I get the below error message

> invalid variable name "docker-compose.yml"

I have installed and uninstalled docker multiple times.

my Docker version - Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
my docker-compose version - Docker Compose version v2.0.0-rc.3

Answer (score 1):

Check that your environment variables or .env file **does not contain multiline variables** (e.g. SSH keys). After flattening them, error should disappear. Source: https://github.com/Azure/aci-deploy/issues/29